# How to get the maximum width from a list of images using openCV?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, concatenation

I do three images with different sizes of (72,153,3), (74,153,3), (75,153,3) and (71,153,3).

I am trying to get the max width from these four images which is 75. I have done a bit of coding to read the files from a list using openCV and I don't know how to move forward from there.

```
image_names = ["POPI_133.png", "POPI_134.png", "POPI_135.png", "POPI_135.png"]
images = []

for name in image_names:
    # open all images and find their sizes
    images.append(cv2.imread(name))
```

I really don't know how to forward with these code afterwards. Kindly help please!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to obtain the result you need..

```
import cv2

image_paths = ["POPI_133.png", "POPI_134.png", "POPI_135.png", "POPI_135.png"]

max_width = 0

for img_path in image_paths:
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    width = img.shape[1]

    if width > max_width:
        max_width = width

print(max_width)
```

If you wanted to get the max `height` of all the images you'll need to replace `img.shape[1]` with `img.shape[0]` in the code.